Should I omit "that" or not?
I think she has a better chance of being promoted than you!
"What do you mean? THAT I'm less smart than her?"
"What do you mean? I'm less smart than her?"
Should I omit "that" in the question above?

I think the version with "that" is more idiomatic, but it's optional.

You can use that or omit it. Both are valid and there's no difference in meaning.
However, it really should be:

"What do you mean? [That] I'm less smart than she?"

But even that sounds a little too formal, so I would say:

"What do you mean? [That] I'm not as smart as she [is]?"

